# How can I treat internet disconnection

Tags: c#

I have a program that gets all files in the target directory including files in the sub-directories. It calls a function for each file and then creates another 2 files.
The problem is that there is a big number of files, the folders in which I plan to target with this program is in a server that I need internet acess.
I plan to run this overnights a few times but the problem is that if the internet goes down for a second,the program might give some erro. How can I make sure that if internet goes down,the program will keep trying to read/write in the server until it comes back?

```
private void bw1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    String ar = (String) e.Argument;
    String outFolder = Path.Combine(ar, "outputFolder");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(outFolder);
    DirSearch(ar,outFolder);
}

private void DirSearch(String sDir,String outFolder)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
        {
            goRun(f,outFolder);
        }

        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
           if(!Path.GetFileName(d).Equals("outputFolder"))  DirSearch(d,outFolder);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void goRun(String path,String outFolder)
{
    String[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    String firstPath = Path.Combine(outFolder,"out1.txt")
    String secondPath = Path.Combine(outFolder,"out2.txt")
    //do something
    File.WriteAllLines(outputPath, outputOne);
    File.WriteAllLines(secondPath, outputTwo);
}
```

This is the idea that I came up with, if there a better solution?

```
 private void DirSearch(String sDir,String outFolder)
        {
            try
            {
        String[] files;
        String[] dirs;

        while(true){
            if(Directory.Exists(sDir)){
                files = Directory.GetFiles(sDir);
                dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(sDir);
                break;
            }
        }
                foreach (string f in files)
                {
                    goRun(f,outFolder);
                }

                foreach (string d in dirs)
                {
                   if(!Path.GetFileName(d).Equals("outputFolder"))  DirSearch(d,outFolder);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

private void goRun(String path,String outFolder){
    String[] fileLines;
    String firstPath = Path.Combine(outFolder,"out1.txt")
    String secondPath = Path.Combine(outFolder,"out2.txt")

        while(true){
            if(File.Exists(path)){
                fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
                break;
            }
        }
    //do something

        while(true){
            if(Directory.Exists(outFolder)){
                File.WriteAllLines(outputPath, outputOne);
                File.WriteAllLines(secondPath, outputTwo);
                break;
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: You are asking about the internet going down, but I don't see anywhere in your code that you make a web call. It seems to me that you are just doing everything with local files, so why would the internet connection matter? Am I just missing something?

Comment: Have you considered using something like the Microsoft Sync Framework (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync)? Specifically the File Synchronization Provider (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887623). I think it would address your issue of intermittent connectivity.

Comment: @Kevin
The path for the direcotories and files are network locations.

Comment: Gotcha, in that case I think the path I would take would be to wrap all of the functions that make the network reads and catch the possible exceptions that would come from network connectivity issues, and just continue trying to get the data until the connection comes back up. If you want to pursue that path but need a code example let me know and I'll write an actual answer